# How to run Angular app on xampp server?

Tags: php, angular, xampp

I'm working with Angular 2 with php. Before I started PHP with Angular 2. I have done Angular 2 with node.js on server localhost:3000. Now with PHP, how I can configure my Angular 2 app with xampp server so my server code is running on localhost:8080. Please help me on this.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Here is my answer.

You can write Angular2 app just using Angular2 packages without using node or mamp or xampp and host that app. [Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35795246/angular-2-nodejs-vs-xampp)

According to the above reference I created my app using angular 2 - cli
after that I made a little change in my root directory index.html file which is:

```
<base href="/">
```

into

```
<base href="./">
```

and build my app using:

```
ng build --prod
```

copy dist folder and paste it in my xampp htdocs folder and access the site using:

> localhost:8080/dist/

**output**

App works

Comment: @Ahmer Ali Ahsan this doesn't work for me with angular 5

Comment: @sk555 This answer is for angular 2. If you have facing issues in angular 5 related to my question kindly post it on Stack overflow.

Comment: @AhmerAliAhsan thanks is there any way to deploy angular ?

Comment: Plunker & Stackblitz.com

Comment: after refresh the page it's not working. for that what to do?

Comment: Doesn't works for me as well

Answer (score 5):

You can host it on any server by first building the angular project using the command line:

```
ng build --base-href "/football/" --prod
```

This base href will mean that it expects the final server to be something like: 
localhost:8080/football/.

You want to get everything that is made in the dist folder and paste it into your server inside a folder called football.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are looking something similar to:

[angular-cli server - how to proxy API requests to another server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37172928/angular-cli-server-how-to-proxy-api-requests-to-another-server)

Just run your angular 2 application using the CLI, and add the proxy to use the services that are in xampp.