# How to run the Angular2 and Codeigniter on same server

Tags: node.js, angular, codeigniter, webpack, apache2

I have a Codeigniter application with Angular2. 
Angualr2 runs on node webpack. 
Codeigniter run on XAMPP Apache.

How to run both on same Server.? Please advise.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44640670/how-to-run-angular2-app-on-xampp-server

Comment: Great, is posible to run the codeigniter on node webpack.

Comment: Not sure. I've never used it. But this solves your issue unless theres something more you are doing on the node server than just serving the angular application.